# async / await resolves without promise finishing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
const handleStatus = (ref, error = "Unknown error") => {
  ref.child("status").on("value", snapshot => {
    const status = snapshot.val();
    if (status === SUCCESS) {
      ref.child("status").off();
      return Promise.resolve(error);
    } else if (status !== PENDING) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
};

export default class Database {
  /**
   * @desc create character
   * @type {Promise}
   */
  static create = async (uid = "", username = "", gender = "", race = "") => {
    try {
      const ref = database.ref(`/void/create/${uid}`);
      await ref.set({ username, gender, race, status: PENDING });
      await handleStatus(ref, "Unable to create character, please try again latter");
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject("Username already taken");
    }
  };
}
```

I'm experiencing issue with above code, particularly `handleStatus` resolving instantly in `Database.create()` function. I expect it to only resolve when `if (status === SUCCESS)` is satisfied (or else statement) which usually takes some time from that `.on("value")` function (coming from firebase if you are interested, but not relevant to the question). At the moment it resolves instantly, nothing within if statement is executed and `Database.create()` still returns, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to construct a Promise which is resolved or rejected on an event. This is not remotely what your code does.

`handleStatus` doesn't actually return anything, because there is no `return` statement in it. The only `return` statements are within the event handler, where they are discarded. In addition, you are misunderstanding `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject`: they are used to create new Promise instances when they are called; again, this is not what you want.

You actually want to create a `new Promise` and return that:

```
const handleStatus = (ref, error = "Unknown error") => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref.child("status").on("value", snapshot => {
      const status = snapshot.val();
      if (status === SUCCESS) {
        ref.child("status").off();
        resolve(error); // is this really what you mean?
      } else if (status !== PENDING) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
};
```